# When I copy and paste something into my document in Overleaf, it puts it all in one line. How do I separate it?

Tags: line-spacing

When I copy and paste a paragraph into Overleaf, it doesn't keep track of the lines on the side, and puts the whole paragraph into one line, shown in the picture. How do I fix it? This happens MANY times and it's a long document, so I can't go and fix each one separately.

[image]

Comment: What is the nature of the text you are pasting? I.e., is it plain text? LaTeX code? Equations?

Comment: This means that you do not have hard line breaks in the original document. Almost every sane editor has options to automatically insert them, for example https://superuser.com/questions/404343/in-notepad-how-do-i-split-long-lines-in-several-rows

Comment: I get this behaviour when cutting-and-pasting code from this site (which surely has hard line breaks) to overleaf on an android device.  I agree that it is highly irritating but I suspect it is a bug with overleaf - I've read elsewhere that overleaf doesn't work properly with copy-and-paste on android devices.

Comment: This suggests using the rich text view https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Can_I_use_Overleaf_on_my_iPad,_Android_tablet,_or_other_mobile_devices%3F

Answer (score 1):

- That is expected behavior.
- Only when there is an ["end of the line"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)*, i. e. when you **press the "Return" ("Enter") key**, then you create a new line.
- If a line is longer than the available visual space then the editor can automatically wrap the line around (automatic lien break but only visually but not logically).
- I added a screenshot from the text editor notepadd++ that tries to illustrate this concept.

[image]

**Typically `LF` (Line Feed) or `CR+LF` (Carriage Return + Line Feed), this originates from mechanical typewriters afaik.*

Comment: I appreciate this, but this tells me *why* it happens, not just that it does. This is riddled through a document that should be over 1500 lines long. I can't go through and hit enter at each line. Whats the fix to do this document-wide?

Comment: @user248189 I do not know. *Why* do you want/need to do that? I go to bed now :).

Comment: I do not know how long the paragraphs are which you copy, and thus, why you need more lines, nor do you tell at which point you want to break the line, but: in TeXShop you can substitute all points by a point plus return % return by "replace all". Doing this, the editor counted 87 lines instead of 13 in some copied text, and produced an empty line after each text line. Maybe you can do the same in Overleaf.